# iPhone - Create PDF using text and image

Tags: iphone, cgpdfdocument

I've some text entered by user in my app and image is captured from camera.
I want to create a PDF using the text and image?
I know how to create a PDF as mentioned in URL [PDF Creation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html)

But I don't know how to create a PDF using both text and image.
Can some one suggest me good tutorial or some sample piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the lines of the example provided at the link you mentioned, you can do something like-

```
CGContextSelectFont (pdfContext, "Arial", 12, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (pdfContext, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (pdfContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);
const char *text = "my text";
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (pdfContext, 50, 375, text, strlen(text)); //Display wherever you want to
```

You can use `CGContextDrawImage` in a similar fashion to display the image.

HTH,

Akshay